# How to print a message in window using open cv

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am working on a face detection use case and want to print a message when the face is not detected in the frame, and draw the bounding box when the face is detected. I am using open-cv for the same
Here is my code so far, please let me know what changes need to be made.

```
import cv2
cascPath = 'haarcascade_frontalface_dataset.xml' 
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  
while True :
    _, frame = video_capture.read(0)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # cv2.imshow("face detection", frame)

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30),
        flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
    )
    # Draw a rectangle around the faces
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        if w == 0:
            cv2.putText(frame,'No face',(0,130), font, 1, (200,255,155))
        else:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    # Display the resulting frame in browser
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything is done, release the capture
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This guide in geeksforgeeks can help you. Also you can follow link on tproger, so I recommend to use google transltator.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-cv2-puttext-method/
https://tproger.ru/translations/opencv-python-guide/#text

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the solution, go through it if you want to have a look , just add this if statement before for loop, it writes no face in the window if no face is detected

```
if len(faces) == 0:
    cv2.putText(frame,'No face',(0,130), 4,1, (200,255,155))
```